# App not properly working on the emulator after android studio upgrade

Tags: android-studio, version, emulation

Hey after an upgrade to my android studio and a change of versionName from "1.0" to "1.2.3" (in build.gradle), my app does not work properly on the emulator.

The app was working before the upgrade, the app is a simple video advertisement (supported by doubleclick) shown on a video. After the upgrade the app shows the video with out the advertisement.

I am quite positive that the problem is with the settings of the emulator but I do not know what setting I should change or how to change it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try to downgrade Android-studio to see if problem is in emulator or not

Comment: Hey, how can I down grade Android Studio?

Comment: I looked it up, it seems you can't. The problem must be somewhere else. Try with different settings of the emulator or if you can, test app on your phone

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put in the answer!

I will try to play around with different emulators.